# Rails where and incrementing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have invitation.rb model and there I have defined invitation method, that should increment User.people by 1 of User with id that is meet_id and friend_id.
The code looks like this:

```
def accept
    transaction do
      self.status = true
      save
      Invitation.delete_all(status: false, meet_id: meet_id)
      User.people.where(id:meet_id, id:friend_id) += 1
    end
```

If you guys could say to me whats wrong that would be very nice :)
**Working solution:**
I moved User.people increment to controller and now invitations_controller.rb looks like

```
user = User.find(@invitation.meet_id)
user.people += 1
user.save
user = User.find(@invitation.friend_id)
user.people += 1
user.save
```

Comment: Operator `+=` rewrites the class. What did you plan to get with the operator?

Comment: Increase value by one of User.people, when User.id = meet_id and friend_id

Comment: you have increased not the `people`, and result of `where`.

Comment: But if I write User.where(id:meet_id, id:friend_id).people +=1 it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes because result of where is a find selector. You shall enumerate all those people, and increase their people value. Am I correct understood that `people` field is the field of `User` model?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Could you show me how I should write it

Comment: try do something like this: `User.where(id:meet_id, id:friend_id).each {| user | user.people += 1 }`. However, I guess you need to add a scope that will count friends for a specific user, which have to go to the meeting.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can reduce your new controller to a simple line: `User.where(id: [meet_id, friend_id]).update_all("people = people + 1")`. If you want to use `find`, no need to increment and save, use: `User.find(@invitation.meet_id).increment!(:people)`

Comment: I would also like to point out that naming is very important: the attribute `people` suggests to be the association. I would prefer if the attribute is very clear in expressing its meaning. So at the very least, call it `people_count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

`User.where(id: [meet_id, friend_id]).update_all("people = people + 1")`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, imho :) This is the most efficient solution.

Comment: I updated my answer to include benchmarks, arieljuods solution is the most efficient, allthough Damiens suggestion is good as well. Mine sucked in efficiency :P

Comment: @TheChamp arieljuod's answer is not the most efficient. Counter_cache and increment_counter will update one row at a time. But, counter_cache is more reliable in that it manages counts on destroy. Your benchmarks show `increment(:people)` which will not perform a query. Use `increment!(:people)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about Counter Cache http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column and ActiveRecord's increment_counter method http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment_counter/class

Both are more "rails" way of incrementing a counter. You can use some of the other answers but rails already simplifies this.

Comment: Yes, but that does assume there also is a relation, which afaik is not the case.

Comment: @nathanvda after looking through the question again, I agree. It is possible, but it looks like you'd have to maintain a self-referencing relationship for users.

Answer (score 0):

The benchmark of the various functions resulted in:

```
1: User.where(:id => [meet_id, friend_id]).each do |u|
     u.people += 1
     u.save!
   end
2: User.where(:id => [meet_id, friend_id]).update_all("people = people + 1")
3: User.where(:id => [meet_id, friend_id]).each { |u| u.increment!(:people) }

   user        system      total     real
1: 0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.040283)
2: 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001638)
3: 0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.077888)
```

So I stand corrected, I wouldn't go by my original function `1:`, best method would be `2:`, as suggested by **Damien**

Comment: These benchmarks are invalid, sadly. 1 and 3 are incrementing a variable, whereas 2 is incrementing a column in the database. To compare, you will have to also save those records: `u.save`, and `u.increment!(:people)`.

Comment: Yup thanks, you're right, was my first bm attempt, well here are the updates!